# ¿Cómo efectuar un backup del servidor (utilizando, por ejemplo, PHP) con acceso FTP raíz limitado al modo read-only?

Tags: php, ftp

Mi servicio de hospedaje en la nube me suspendió recientemente por razón *Anti-hack*. Recibí un correo, en donde el equipo de **OVH** me informa que solamente puedo utilizar FTP con permiso `read-mode` para poder solamente leer (abrir) cualquier archivo (root), es decir, cualquier archivo o directorio/carpeta del servidor.

Debido a que solamente estoy limitado a utilizar el servicio FTP limitado con este modo activado, necesitaré descargar cada uno de los los archivos y carpetas/directorios del servidor, para que sean, posteriormente, comprimidos de manera automática en un solo archivo `.zip`. Pretendo hacer esto utilizando PHP, ahora, como hacerlo es el problema (aunque sea un truco).

Agradezco sus respuestas enormemente.
Me encuentro en una situación bastante alarmante y preoucupante para mí, puesto a que mis servicios, aplicaciones e instancias están abajo. Estoy teniendo la esperanza de que pueda haber algún truco o método de utilizar el modo de FTP limitado que me proveen para poder descargar un backup.

Comment: ¿Tienes acceso `ssh` o no?

Comment: @A. Cedano No tengo acceso SSH. En el panel de control aparecere que el servicio está habilitado, pero desde la suspensión no he podido acceder a SSH. He intentado usando otros nombres de usuarios y puertos incluso el nuevo, pero sale claramente en el email que solamente el servicio FTP read-mode está disponible. Debe haber algo que haga el truco y me permita poder conseguir los contenidos de cada archivo, aunque tome su tiempo.. combinando lenguajes de programación como sea posible. Preferencialmente PHP

Comment: Lamento que te encuentres en  una situación que describes. En este sitio las publicaciones deben seguir ciertos lineamientos. Favor de seguir el [tour] y leer [ask]. Lo anterior para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: @Rubén Estimado Rubén, acabo de actualizar mi publicación.

Comment: @CarlosValle: Hace muchísimo que no uso FTP. Este es un servicio básico. Si mal no recuerdo Windows cuenta con un cliente, tal vez debas agregarlo o también está la alternativa de descargar uno. Si te han provisto con los datos de acceso (url, ¿puerto?, usuario y contraseña) con la documentación básica del manual/ayuda del cliente de FTP deberías poder conectarte, explorar el directorio y hacer la descarga de tus archivos.

Comment: @Rubén Buenas, estás en lo correcto, pero son 5GB. como transfiero tal cantidad y a dónde? Pensé en un script PHP automatizado, pero incluso con el ajuste `ignore_user_abort` el script PHP se pausa en un momento.

Comment: @CarlosValle: Agrega los detalles de tu caso a la pregunta ya que los comentarios son para cuestiones temporales como solicitar aclaración o criticar una pregunta/respuesta.

Comment: @Rubén Disculpe, aún no soy usuario **registrado**.

Comment: [¿Por qué debo crear una cuenta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/why-register)

Answer (score 0):

Yo me descargaría el [Filezilla](https://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client) u otro cliente FTP y me descargaría la web a mi equipo. Y luego ya vería de subirla a otro sitio si tu proveedor actual no te lo permite. Aunque seguramente tu problema será que lo que tienes alojado tiene algún bug y algún cracker lo ha aprovechado para hacer alguna maldad.

Si tu proveedor no te deja subir nada al sitio web por FTP (dices que lo tienes en modo lectura solamente), y tienes la web bloqueada no te quedan muchas otras opciones.